# Pandas groupby with lambda and condition

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe:

```
    d = {'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
         'value': [10, 8, 7, 7, 0, 2, 9, 4, 0, 9, 10, 4, 5, 5],
         'box': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
         'fruit': ['apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'lime', 'lime', 'orange',
                   'orange', 'lime', 'orange', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple',
                   'orange', 'orange']
         }
    dummy_df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

I would like to create a column with standardized values, with conditions: I want to standardize the values by box column, but use the values for calculating the mean and the standard deviation from only the apple items. So instead of using the mean (box1_mean: 6.14, box2_mean: 5.28) and std (box1_std: 3.71, box2_std: 3.35) of each box, I would like to use only the "apple" values to calculate it (box1_apple_mean: 8.33, box1_apple_std: 1.52, box2_apple_mean:   7.66, box2_apple_std: 3.21).

Desired output would look like this:

[image: Desired output]

I have this line of code to perform the standardization by box, but this doesn't give me the desired output.

```
dummy_df['value_apple_stand'] = dummy_df.groupby('box')['value'].transform(lambda x: (x-x.mean())/x.std())
```

How to put the extra information to take into account in calculating the mean and std from only the values where fruit is apple?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What if there's no apple ?

Comment: yes, that's a fair question, in my real data I've checked and all the "boxes" contain "apples"

Comment: Is your question about calculating standardization of value or about calculating it in one line?

Comment: It's about calculating the standardization in the described way. I don't care how many lines there are in the solution, but I suspect there is a one-liner for this that I don't know about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `apply` instead of `transform`. With `apply` you have access to all columns which you can use to filter and calculate `mean` and `std` for specific conditions:

```
def norm_by(g, fruit):
    fruit_value = g['value'][g['fruit'] == fruit]
    return (g.value - fruit_value.mean()) / fruit_value.std()

dummy_df['value_apple_stand'] = \
    dummy_df.groupby('box', group_keys=False).apply(norm_by, 'apple')

dummy_df
    ID  value  box   fruit  value_apple_stand
0    1     10    1   apple           1.091089
1    2      8    1   apple          -0.218218
2    3      7    1   apple          -0.872872
3    4      7    1    lime          -0.872872
4    5      0    1    lime          -5.455447
5    6      2    1  orange          -4.146140
6    7      9    1  orange           0.436436
7    8      4    2    lime          -1.140647
8    9      0    2  orange          -2.384989
9   10      9    2   apple           0.414781
10  11     10    2   apple           0.725866
11  12      4    2   apple          -1.140647
12  13      5    2  orange          -0.829561
13  14      5    2  orange          -0.829561
```

Answer (score 1):

to have the mean of the `value_apple_stand` where fruit is equal to apple, you can do this;

```
df.loc[df['fruit'] == 'apple', 'value_apple_stand'].mean()
```

Otherwhise, applying a lambda function, to have the mean() for each type of fruit:

```
df.groupby(['fruit']).apply(lambda x: x['value_apple_stand'].mean())
```